# Is it better to link libraries or bring them to local directory where test.c code resides?

Tags: c, matplotlib, linker, shared-libraries, plplot

I am struggling to understand linking process in c.  (I am new in C)  When I make object  a test code in my local directory (plplotExample.c and mathglExample) some complain that header are not there even though I have them in usr/local/...., except for mathglExample.   The test codes are below:

plotExample.c

```
 #include "plConfig.h"
 #include "plcdemos.h"
 #define NSIZE    101

 int
 main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
PLFLT x[NSIZE], y[NSIZE];
PLFLT xmin = 0., xmax = 1., ymin = 0., ymax = 100.;
int   i;

// Prepare data to be plotted.
for ( i = 0; i < NSIZE; i++ )
{
    x[i] = (PLFLT) ( i ) / (PLFLT) ( NSIZE - 1 );
    y[i] = ymax * x[i] * x[i];
}

// Parse and process command line arguments
plparseopts( &argc, argv, PL_PARSE_FULL );

// Initialize plplot
plinit();

// Create a labelled box to hold the plot.
plenv( xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, 0, 0 );
pllab( "x", "y=100 x#u2#d", "Simple PLplot demo of a 2D line plot" );

// Plot the data that was prepared above.
plline( NSIZE, x, y );

// Close PLplot library
plend();

exit( 0 );
 }
```

the error message is :

```
 plplotExample.c:2:10: fatal error: plConfig.h: No such file or directory
```

mathglExample.c

```
 #include <mgl2/mgl_cf.h>
 int main()
 {
 HMGL gr = mgl_create_graph(600,400);
 mgl_fplot(gr,"sin(pi*x)","","");
 mgl_write_frame(gr,"test.png","");
 mgl_delete_graph(gr);
 }
```

the error message is

```
 In file included from /usr/include/mgl2/mgl_cf.h:29:0,
             from mathglExample.c:1:
          /usr/include/mgl2/data_cf.h:513:17: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘mgl_find_roots’
```

how to fix linking or should I bring all codes and libraries under one directory? I am using linux opensuse leap 15.2 and Geany as c editor.

Comment: The errors you are showing are not related to libraries or linking. Headers are not libraries. Inclusion is not linking.

Comment: You have to tell the comiler where to find the include files with the `-I` option. If you are using a build tool (as you should) then how to set compile options depends on the build tool. What build tool are you using? If you are using an IDE that has its own build tool, then what IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using make to make and gcc to build and compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `plConfig.h` has to be in the same directory as `plotExample.c`.
2. In the file `/usr/include/mgl2/data_cf.h`, on the line 513, at the column 17, the compiler expects a ',' or a ';' before `mgl_find_roots`

As already mentioned, inclusion is not linking. You have in case 1 a file not found error and in case 2 an error in the source code.

1. Read this on how to include header files: [Source file inclusion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/include) (or since you're using linux and geany, the compiler is presumably gcc: [GNU CPP Header Files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html#Header-Files))
2. Try to read and understand the compiler messages.

**Addendum** (based on your comment)

`-I plplot` is a relative directory. That means, the compiler is searching in your current working directory for a directory named `plplot`. Either use the compiler option `-I /usr/include/plplot` or use the following inclusion in your source files (without the `-I` compiler option):

```
#include <plplot/the_relevant_header_file.h>
```

As I understand it, the 'pl...' headers are part of a third party lib (that your project depends on) and is installed e.g. by the system or make, in either case, don't pick random headers (from that project) and relocate them and try to include them from that directory. Because, the headers itself might (presumably) include other headers from that lib. In such a case, use either the -I option (not recommended) or avoid the compiler option (recommended) and include from the system path as described in my example above. The reason for that is, that from your include directive (#include <plplot/...>) you're able to see, from which library you (and not only you, but most importantly others) are including the symbols from.

Comment: I placed plcdemos.h, plplot.h and plConfig.h into the same directory as plotExample.c. I added a flag called (capital i for plplot) "-I plplot - lm" to build because all  h files except plcdemos.h are  in usr/include/plplot/ directory.  and still  getting error. The message is make plplotExample.o
cc    -c -o plplotExample.o plplotExample.c
In file included from plcdemos.h:13:0,
                 from plplotExample.c:3:
plplot.h:128:10: fatal error: pldll.h: No such file or directory
 #include "pldll.h"
          ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: plplotExample.o] Error 1

Comment: Related to your comment, i've added some more info to my answer. Hope that gives you more insight. I still recommend to read the linked articles (for a better understanding).

Comment: I did some modifications based on your addendum.  I placed plcdemos.h that original test code was referring to locally where the test code is.  I have checked that header for its headers and it was referring to plplot.h and plConfig.h.  I wrote the include properly as you mentioned in addendum.  The make object went smoothly and completely.  However, the build command failed with lots of messages regarding the undefined reference to 6 functions.h.. .  Looks like plplot.h or plConfig.h inclusions are broken originally.

Comment: Those 6 functions are defined in plplot.h.   So why build does not see their definitions in header file?

Comment: Finally I fixed it.   I had to flag build command with -lplplot and it works nicely.  Thank you.